# How can I base64 encode a string on linux so it matches windows "Unicode.GetBytes.ToBase64String"?

Tags: linux, bash, powershell, character-encoding, base64

This question probably has been answered, but I couldn't find it

**Question**

How can I 'base64 encode' a string in bash so it matches "what windows expects", i.e.  "Unicode.GetBytes.ToBase64String"

**Context**

The powershell help text has this example

```
$command='dir'
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
echo $encodedCommand
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

**Windows Output**

The encoded output is this:

```
ZABpAHIA
```

**Very Different results on linux**

If I do the same thing on linux, I get this:

```
echo "dir" | base64
ZGlyCg==
```

**Encodings?**

I've tried using "iconv" to convert encodings, but no luck, i.e same results.

echo dir |iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-8   |base64

**Differences**

So you can see two differences:

- Alphanumeric characters differ
- Trailing "===" appears on linux

Comment: Using `printf` is preferable than `echo -n`: `variable='dir'; printf '%s' "$variable"`.

Comment: Trailing = are used for padding. The string is probably padded because its length is 4. In fact, every 3 original bytes would give 4 encoded bytes as 3 x 8 bits = 4 x 6 bits.

Comment: Make sure to use the echo -n option to prevent a new line character to be fed into base64. Then, in PowerShell, use UTF8 instead of Unicode. Then both Bash and PowerShell yield the same result: "ZGly".

Answer (score 3):

Unicode in Powershell is UTF16 LE, not UTF8.

> Unicode: Encodes in UTF-16 format using the little-endian byte order.

Source: [Set-Content for FileSystem](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847827.aspx)

I don't use linux, but if your utf8-sample above works, then you could try:

```
iconv -f ASCII -t UTF-16 mycmd.txt |base64
```

If you plan to bring a string encoded in Powershell into Linux then do the following, first encode in Powershell

```
$string = "That's no moon!"
[system.convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::unicode.getbytes($String))

VABoAGEAdAAnAHMAIABuAG8AIABtAG8AbwBuACEA
```

Then in Linux do the following:

```
echo VABoAGEAdAAnAHMAIABuAG8AIABtAG8AbwBuACEA | base64 -d | iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8; echo

That's no moon!
```

Comment: `UTF-16LE` might be the encoding needed for `iconv`.

Comment: I would also think that Linux encode the string null terminator but not Windows since otherwise Linux encoded string would probably be 4 bytes.

Comment: @Phil1970: not the null terminator, but the newline character output by `echo`. Try with `printf dir | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE | base64`.

Comment: not familiar with iconv and what arguments it accepts, so I'm not gonna argue between `UTF-16` and `UTF-16LE` :-)